# Use of 'self' in property access 'frame' before super.init initializes self

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have this code

```
import UIKit

class CardView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    init(imageView: UIImageView) {
        self.imageView = imageView
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height))
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

I get an error at the line:

```
super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height))
```

The error says `Use of 'self' in property access 'frame' before super.init initializes self`

I don't have any idea how to solve this.

Please bare in mind I am from an objective - C background and recently started learning swift.

Comment: what value is `self.frame.size.width` supposed to have? Just replace it with `0` when calling `super.init`

Comment: i know that it doesnt give error but i want the value to be the self.frame.size.width. @luk2302

Comment: You are not making any sense. What value are you expecting it to return? Think about it this way: `frame` is initialized in `super.init`, it does not *exist* yet where you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must call `super.init()` before accessing `self` within a `init()` method:

```
init(imageView: UIImageView) {
    self.imageView = imageView /*you are accessing self here before calling super init*/
    super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: self.frame.size.width /* here also*/, height: self.frame.size.height))
}
```

Change it to:

```
init(imageView: UIImageView) {
    super.init(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: imageView.frame.size))
    self.imageView = imageView 
}
```

Comment: That does not make any sense. What  is in `self.frame`?

Comment: Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIView' i get this error

Comment: @Aryan Fixed it. Sorry.

Comment: @Sulthan Correct. Just took care of the error in question. Changed it to use parameters frame now.

Comment: @shallowThought Now, you can directly call `super.init(frame: )` with the correct frame instead of calling it with `CGRect.zero` and then changing it.

Comment: @Sulthan Correct too :-) Changed again.

Comment: @shallowThought Just a minor point, a `CGRect` can be also initialized as `CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: imageView.frame.size)`.

Comment: @Sulthan Nicer, agree.

Comment: Why not use frame: imageView.bounds? bounds is local coordinate system (0,0,widt,height) and frame is its superview coordinate system so (x,y,width,height).

Comment: Many ways to go. I did not think much about this and also not about how useful this initializer is in general. Just wanted to point out not to use `self` before calling `super.init()`. Feel free to edit it.