# Order of setting variables and super.init in init, both give errors

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

I have the following code:

```
class EditorWindow: NSWindow {
    @Binding var keycode : Int

    override func keyDown(with event : NSEvent) {
        super.keyDown(with: event)
        Swift.print("Caught a key down: \(event.keyCode)!")
    }

    init(keycode : Int){
        self.keycode = keycode
        super.init(contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
                   styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
                   backing: .buffered, defer: false)
    }
}
```

Placing the self.keycode = keycode before the super.init gives me the error "'self' used in property access 'keycode' before 'super.init' call", (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41779219/use-of-self-in-property-access-frame-before-super-init-initializes-self), which suggests to swap the order). If I swap the order, I get the error: "Property 'self.keycode' not initialized at super.init call" (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021093/error-in-swift-class-property-not-initialized-at-super-init-call) which suggests the *original order* as the solution) - it seems whichever order I use I get an error - how do I get around this?

Comment: What is the keycode guy for?

Comment: Call super.init first and see if setting keykode as weak (weak var keykode: Int) fixes it.

Comment: Why do you neeed `@Binding` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a `Binding<Int>` to the constructor:

```swift
    init(keycode : Binding<Int>){
        self._keycode = keycode
        super.init( // .....
    }
```